# Evaluating FourierTransform like integral manually

Tags: integral-transforms, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to evaluate

```
Integrate[x^2*Exp[I k (x - 1)], {k, -∞, ∞}, {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

Since $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ik(x-1)} d{k}$ is $\delta(x-1)$, answer should be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2[2\pi \delta(x-1)] dx =2\pi$.

However, Mathematica says that the integral does not converge.

Comment: Am I missing something?

Comment: The integral diverges. Probably better to use `FourierTransform` in such cases.

Comment: `Integrate` doesn't venture into generalized function territory for divergent integrals, so it won't yield an expression with `DiracDelta` in it.

Comment: The improper  integral under consideration diverges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like OP is interested in seeing how the integral can be done without using a black box like `FourierTransform` function. As mentioned in the comments, when we do not think of this integral as a distribution, it behaves badly and seems to diverge. Therefore, it is useful to regularize the integral by introducing a small parameter `ϵ` which makes it convergent. For example

```
integral[k_] = Integrate[Exp[-ϵ k^2 + I k f], k]
```

> [image]

where `Erfi` is the [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function). The above result is an anti-derivative, which we can trivially verify to be correct by taking the derivative:

```
D[integral[k], k] // ExpandAll
```

> [image]

We also can use that anti-derivative to evaluate the integral over `-∞ < k < ∞`:

```
Assuming[Element[{ϵ, f, k}, Reals] && ϵ > 0,
   result = Series[integral[k] - integral[-k], {k, ∞, 0}] // Normal
]
```

> [image]

The `Series` expansion was not perfect since the exponential function is non-perturbative in powers of `k`; but it was good enough, since we can now see that all the terms still dependent on `k` go to zero for `k -> ∞`. So that actually

```
result = (E^(-(f^2/(4 ϵ))) Sqrt[π])/Sqrt[ϵ];
```

Of course, in Mathematica we can arrive at this directly without making reference to any anti-derivative

```
result = Integrate[Exp[-ϵ k^2 + I k f], {k, -∞, ∞}]
```

> [image]

You might notice that this result is essentially a [limit representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/0004/) of the `DiracDelta` function:

[image]

However, it is not necessary for us to recognize this and substitute anything by hand. We can simply proceed with the second integration by specifying `f = x-1` and multiplying by `x^2`:

```
Integrate[
  x^2 (E^(-((x - 1)^2/(4 ϵ))) (Sqrt[π]))/ Sqrt[ϵ]
, {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

> [image]

Sure enough, you get the expected result, and can now drop the `ϵ` regulator.

While `ϵ>0` is a requirement for convergence, we can pick it to be as small as we like. Asymptotically, in the limit `ϵ->+0` the result becomes indistinguishable from the one where `ϵ` is actually zero. This is what is implied when we say we "drop" the regulator. Additionally, recall that `ϵ` was not there initially and was introduced as a tool to be able to calculate. So at the end we certainly are looking for ways to minimize/remove the effect of `ϵ` to have an equality between initial and final expression where `ϵ` does not appear, in a consistent manner. That is what we do by "dropping" `ϵ` as described above.

Comment: Can you kindly base your "can now drop the ϵ regulator"? Pay your attention at Re[\[Epsilon]>0].

Comment: @user64494 I added some discussion to the answer.

Comment: (1) Dropping the regulator is actually how one defines the generalized integral (the "usual" integral is divergent). You get an expression that has a limiting value, and define that limit as the generalized integral. (2) I liked (and upvoted) this answer. Just wanted to point out what it is that is being defined (you knew but I'm not sure it was clear).

Answer (score 1):

After a variable substitition $x\to x+1$,

```
Sqrt[2π]*FourierTransform[(x + 1)^2, x, k]
```

> Sqrt[2π] (Sqrt[2π] DiracDelta[k] - 2 I Sqrt[2π] DiracDelta'[k] - 
>      Sqrt[2π] DiracDelta''[k])

```
Integrate[%, {k, -∞, ∞}]
```

> 2π

Comment: The integral Integrate[%, {k, -∞, ∞}] in the above makes no sense (e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function ).

Comment: @user64494 Can you please give more details about why you think it makes no sense to integrate the Dirac $\delta$-distribution and its derivatives? From what I know, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(k)dk=1$ is a central property of this distribution, and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(k)dk=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta''(k)dk=0$ as well.